# Printing insert query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I know the if I try to do a select query using the ORM I can use the `print` method to print the SQL to be generated:

`print session.query(MyModel)` should return `select * from MyModel` (the exact SQL may be different but the idea is there).

I now have a piece of code where I create a parent object, loop over some data to create child objects that connect to the parent object with a  [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) then call `session.add(parent_object)` followed by `session.commit()`.

Except this generates an error I don't think it's possible to generate.

Is there a way to view the SQL statement used to insert the data?

The error generated is:

```
arg = (<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError("(pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) (u'ERROR', u'ERROR', u'22001'... too long for type character varying(10)', u'varchar.c', u'624', u'varchar')",), <traceback object at 0x10c98bb00>)
```

where the value inserted for the only column I have that is a `varchar(10)` is `'7835109626'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could enable [sqlalchemy internal logger](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) to output 
 SQL query:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```